# multiple form data upload using ajax and php in single page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

my doubt is about what if i have

these div tags are hidden using transition effects using a jquery i want to get results of div 1 2 3 in results

```
1 div
  <div id="1">    
   </div>      
2 div
   <div id="2">
    </div>       
3 div
   <div id="3">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="first-sudmit" value="NEXT" onclick="result(this.value)" />
    </div>
    <div id="result">   
        result    
    </div>
```

in js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResult()    
{
    alert("dfadsfdasf");
    xmlhttp.open("GET","result.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and i even tried serialisation tooo..... not running the php script

like

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
function showFormData(oForm) {
   var msg = "The data that you entered for the form with 'name' attribute='" + oForm.name + "': \n";

  submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('result.php', $("#submit_drop,#submit_radio,#submit_check,#submit_text,#submit_drag_text,#submit_drag_img").serialize(), function(data) {
                 $('#results').html(data);
            });           
   alert(msg);
}  
</script>
```

php:

```
   //page1 process
    if(!ekpty($_POST['first-submit']))
    {
        $first1=$_POST['drop1'];
        $first2=$_POST['drop2'];
        $first3=$_POST['drop3'];
        $first4=$_POST['drop4'];
        $first5=$_POST['drop5'];
      for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
      {         
          $sql="INSERT INTO $score1(correct)VALUES('$first[i]')";        
      }                
    }
    else
    {
          print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
          print 'alert("page 1 no answer is attempted")'; 
          print '</script>'; 
    }
//output resu;ts
$sql="SELECT count(chkpt) from score1 where chkpt='1'";    
echo $sql;
```

so now how to get the results of those forms in last result div tag.......

please some answer this.......

Comment: If it's jQuery why not using jQuery code? Sample is hard to read, the first HTML sample is malformed (I suppose the numbers 1, 2 and 3 aren't in the code really), and I can't find the declaration of the function "result" (did you mean onclick=showResult ?). Could you clarify? Tanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the response its is onclick=showresult but am new to jquery so i got each page diff jquery i really appreciate it if u give one common to all of em..... like each of my div i got form with 5 questions(radio buttons)..... i want to produce the result in last div tag...

Comment: So you want to get the values of all inputs and controls but they aren't inside a form tag? Am I right?

Comment: i used form but each div tag i got one form can we get those all results to last div even individually by div tag like div 1 result and div 2 results ....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit difficult to read, but if I understand what you're asking I believe your serialization code would work, however I believe you need to use the ID of the form that contains the elements you wish to serialize. So:

```
1 div
  <div id="1">
     <form id="firstFormToSubmit">......</form>
   </div>      
2 div
   <div id="2">
     <form id="secondFormToSubmit">......</form>
    </div>       
3 div
   <div id="3">
    <form id="thirdFormToSubmit">......</form>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="first-sudmit" value="NEXT" onclick="result(this.value)" />
    </div>
    <div id="result">   
        result    
    </div>
```

And then to handle these forms:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('result.php', $("#firstFormToSubmit").serialize(), function(data) {
             $('#results').html(data);
        });
```